# Angular UI-Router - wait for content to load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, routes, angular-ui-router

Using UI-Router with Angular 1.7 and I need to change the state and wait for the content to load and only then, scroll to the bottom of the page.

```js
// Class method
onCreate() {
    this.post().then(response => {
        this.$state.go('root.post.edit', { postId: response.data.id });
        this.Alert.register('success');
    })
    .then(() => scrollToBottom()) // This happens too soon
    .catch(e => this.handleError(e));
}

//scrollToBottom.js
const scrollToBottom () => {
    const scrollContainer = document.querySelector('.app-page-content');
    scrollContainer.scrollTop = scrollContainer.scrollHeight;
};
```

If I wrap the scrollToBottom function contents in a `setTimeout(() => {...}, 600)` then it gives it time to load and scroll to the bottom of the loaded page. However, without it, the page has no height as it's in it's loading state when `scrollContainer.scrollHeight` is calculated.

Is there a way to wait for the content to load on a route you're navigating to?

Answer (score 0):

Use ui-router resolve. Return the promise with the data and it will be readily available when the controller loads. No need for timeouts

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that out. I can't see any examples in the docs of integrating that with $state.go(). Any ideas?

Comment: If you integrate the resolve on the route you need it for. $state.go will simply work.

Comment: Ah I see, so it will get called anytime that route is loaded? I need to only call it in specific instances like in the `onCreate` method in my code example. For instance, I also have a `onPublish` method that navigates to the same route with $state.go() but I don't want my scrolling function to be called

Comment: Yes the resolve will work anytime the state is navigated to. You could use a flag to scroll or not.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS components expose the [`$onInit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture) function/callback that runs when the component finishes loading, this happens after state resolving is finished so all your resolves are available and child components are also done loading.

```
// inside your controller
this.$onInit = function() {
    // ... other initializations ...
    scrollToBottom();
}
```

Comment: The problem with that I found was that because my component has a lot of child components, even though the parent itself was initialised, all the child components had not finished rendering. This meant that it scrolled to the bottom of the page, but then more content was added after and you were only half way down the page

Comment: then ui-router may not hold the solution you need because those components load a lot after the transition finished. other options can be watching values or registering a callback that runs when a set of components finish loading/rendering, etc..

Comment: Yeah I found a lot of talk in other questions about this being an issue with AngularJs development in general. There's no reliable way to use any built in methods to check that all the components and children have been loaded and all the models updated and bindings etc...
using `$timeout()` to wait for the digest cycle to finish helped but again wasn't reliable enough to know how many children components had loaded.
I had to change approach here and make a change to the UI so that I didn't need to scroll :( Unfortunate.

Comment: I guess you'll have to know beforehand how many components need to initialize and write up some logic that checks their progress and does something when they all complete, I'd probably use a queue of promises and utilize $q.all to callback when they all resolve, when a new components needs loading, recreate another queue, et cetera